# Is there a sane way to stack Laravel 5.7 config files?

Tags: laravel, config, laravel-5.7

I've got one codebase that runs multiple variations of the same site. Is there a neat way to have config files that extend each other so that I can have one parent config file with multiple children that override specific values?

Something like this,

```
config/site.php
  return [
    'foo' => 10,
    'bar' => 20,
    'baz' => 30
  ];

config/site1/site.php
  return [
    'foo' => 5,
  ];

config/site2/site.php
  return [
    'baz' => 99
  ];
```

which lets you get the following values back

```
 echo config('site1.site.foo'); // 5  - from site1/site.php
 echo config('site1.site.bar'); // 20 - from site.php
 echo config('site1.site.baz'); // 30 - from site.php

 echo config('site2.site.foo'); // 10 - from site.php
 echo config('site2.site.bar'); // 20 - from site.php
 echo config('site2.site.baz'); // 99 - from site2/site.php
```

It feels like there's a trivial answer I'm missing...

Comment: Are these different variations are running on their own different instances? Maybe you can use the `.env` file then.

Comment: It's one site/codebase that's available through something like 20 different subdomains. Each subdomain is basically the same as the others but has different database tables, stats tracking codes, language options, and integrations to a third party API.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only thing I can think of and assuming you have multiple instances.

1) In your environment variable add `CLIENT=site1`

2) Create a config file e.g:
**tenant.php**

```
return [
   'folder' => env('CLIENT', 'default')
];
```

3) When you need specific config file for one of your client:

```
config(config('tenant.folder')'.site.baz');
```

4) If you need the default value when `baz` does't exists

```
config(config('tenant.folder')'.site.baz', 'default.site.baz');
```

---

A much better way would be to create a database of settings that you could cache and use with helpers (like: `$baz = settings('baz', 'default');`)

Answer (score 0):

I will create a global function that do tenant aware configs, like this:

```php
function configWithTenant($tenant='', $configPath) {
   if (empty($tenant)) {
    return config($configPath);
   }

   return config("$tenant.$configpath");
}
```

so when you call this function, if no tenant is passed in, it will read the default one which is site , else it will read tenant1.site